# Without using jquery, how can I show a div after the user has scrolled 100px?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a div that is fixed to the footer of my website that is positioned using CSS and not visible on page load.  I would like it to show once the user has scrolled at least 100px down on the page and hide when the user has scrolled back up.  I've seen examples here on stackoverflow and other sites that use jquery to do this, but I am looking for a javascript only solution.

I included a jquery version that illustrates what I want to do, but I am not sure how to do this using just javascript.

```
<style type="text/css">
.footerbar{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  display:none;
}
</style>

<div id="fixed-footer" class="footerbar">some text and images here</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {              
        ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) / $(document).height() > 0.50 ? $('#fixed-footer').fadeIn() : $('#fixed-footer').fadeOut();
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction();
}

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || 
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
            document.querySelector('#fixed-footer').style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#fixed-footer').style.display = "none";
        }
}
```

Here is the function...then use css to fade-in and fade-out